# Elasticsearch 7.6.2 service not starting on CentOS 7.x with cPanel installed on it

Tags: elasticsearch, cpanel, magento2, centos7

I have installed elasticsearch version 7.2.6 on CentOS 7.x with cPanel on it. However, after installing it, elasticsearch service is not running. Here is the screen capture of the error.  I have already tried. https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360055446413-How-To-Install-Run-Elasticsearch but the issue is not resolved. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

I have set my IP address in network.host

Comment: It looks like you are starting a new version of Elasticsearch on older data (or vice versa) and both are not compatible. Can you explain the context? Are you starting fresh or on some older data which wasn't properly upgraded?

Comment: It is a fresh installation. I am looking to run Magento 2.4 and it requires elasticsearch 7.6.x. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/elasticsearch.html

Comment: It looks like there is older data causing the error you're seeing. Did you have a previous installation of Magento with an older ES version and you're upgrading on top of it?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Are you referring to the data of an older or another version? Should I uninstall and remove the elastic search directories and try to install it again?

Comment: Yes, if you had a previous version of ES you cannot just install a newer version on top of it, there's an [upgrade path you need to follow](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/setup-upgrade.html). Are you in this situation?

Comment: I have tried a fresh install but the same issue :(

Comment: Did you clean the `/var/lib/elasticsearch` folder?

Comment: After deleting /var/lib/elasticsearch,i have reinstalled it and it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have data from an older ES install. If you're installing a new version and want to keep your older data, you need to go through the [upgrade path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/setup-upgrade.html).

otherwise, if you don't care about your older data and simply want to install the newer version, simply delete the content of `/var/lib/elasticsearch` and install the new version.